# Condition on the relational model Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hello and thanks in advance for your time and help. I have 3 very simple tables. A user table with a user_id, a games table with a game_id as well as some other fields (scheduled date/time) and a GamesAttendee table that just has user_id and game_id field. I am trying to select all games that user is connected to and only return ones that are scheduled for the future/past.

What I ended up going with is:

```
$cur = GamesAttendee::where('user_id',$user_id)->pluck('game_id')->all();
$cur = Game::whereIn('id', $cur)->where('scheduled','>=',$now)->get();
```

But I feel like there has to be a more efficient way of doing this. I have looked around and tried various things like eager loading and just messing with my models and nothing seems to work. I feel like this a very simple and essential case that is extremely common and I am wondering how this is actually supposed to be done in laravel.

I have tried:

`$cur = Game::with(['attendees'=>function($q) use ($user_id){
            return $q->where('user_id',$user_id);
        }])->where('scheduled','>=',$now)->get();`

But that was not what I wanted. I am basically trying to do:

```
SELECT * FROM GameAttendees 
JOIN `games` on games.id = GameAttendees.game_id 
WHERE GameAttendees.user_id = 'x' AND games.scheduled >= '2016/05/01' ;
```

I quickly jotted that mysql code so just ignore any mistakes. Any ideas?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

Resolved by adding the following into my user model:

```
public function future_games()
{
        $now = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+4 hours'));
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Game','games_attendees')->where('scheduled','>=',$now);
}
```

then in my controller I was able to do:

```
$future_games = User::with('future_games')->get();
```

Comment: What does this return. `dd(Game::with(['attendees'=>function($q) use ($user_id){ return $q->where('user_id',$user_id); }])->where('scheduled','>=',$now)->toSql());`

Comment: Can you do:     $cur= Game::whereScheduled('>=', '$now')->whereHas(['attendees' => function ($) {
        $q->whereUserId($user_id);
    
    }])->get();  dd($cur) and post your results please

Comment: The problem with doing an eager load is that it still returns games in the future. I need it to not return anything if there are no one attending. You can see that first I get a list of game_ids that the user is attending, and THEN I look though that list and filter out one that are scheduled for the future. This way I ONLY get games that the user is attending that are in the future. Again, I appreciate your help and responses..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First define many-to-many relation in your Game and User models:

```
class Game extends Model {
  public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'GameAttendees');
  }
}

class User extends Model {
  public function games() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Game::class, 'GameAttendees');
  }
}
```

With that in place you should be able to get all games given user is attending with:

```
$games = $user->games;
```

If you want to add some additional conditions, do the following:

```
$futureGames = $user->games()->where('scheduled','>=',$now)->get();
```

Or just create another relation in your User model:

```
class User extends Model {
  public function futureGames() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Game::class, 'GameAttendees')->where('scheduled','>=',$now);
  }
}
```

and access them by:

```
$futureGames = $user->futureGames;
```

Comment: Yes, but there are 3 different models and tables. The GameAttendees table is just a 2 column table that links user_id and game_ids. Many users can attend many games. But I am going to try and implement some of the logic in your code, but I don't think it's 100% what I was looking for.. But again, thank you for your help already..

Comment: It's a many-to-many relation and with Eloquent you don't need to define the model for the intermediate table - see some examples here https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I am going to implement this now and will update this comment and mark the answer once I do. Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: Let me know if there are any issues or you see any typos, I haven't tested this exact code.

Comment: Yup, that worked flawlessly. You're the man! Thank you. In my future model I did:

`public function future_games() {

        $now = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+4 hours'));
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Game','games_attendees')->where('scheduled','>=',$now);
    }`